# stacking a raster file changes the values, is this correct?

Tags: r

For a project I need to stack multiple raster files, however, when doing so the values change and I am not sure what the cause is.

For context, I have converted a raster format (.tiff) into .asc in QGIS. Here the values display properly, ranging from -10.000 to 10.000. After importing and stacking using the following code in R I get values which are way higher than expected. Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

```
> NDVI <- raster("NDVI.asc")

EVI <- raster("EVI.asc")

NDMI <- raster("NDMI.asc")

veg <- stack(NDVI, EVI, NDMI)

veg
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like an overflow of your 32-bit values, definitely not correct. Why the tiff to asc conversion beforehand? ESRI grid is the least sophisticated format when dealing with raster data. Have you already tried `terra::rast(c("NDVI.tif", "EVI.tif", "NDMI.tif"))`?